# Laravel API URL Parameters and Routing

Tags: php, laravel, api

I've got the following code in my api.php file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    // Return user information
    Route::get('/user', function(Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

    // Return  user runs
    Route::get('/runs', function(Request $request) {
        $user = $request->user('api');

        return $user->runs();
    });

    Route::get('/runs/{id}', function(Request $request, $id) {
        $user = $request->user('api');

        return $user->run($id);
    });

    // Return user profiles
    Route::get('/profiles', function(Request $request) {
        $user = $request->user('api');

        return $user->profiles();
    });

});
```

**API Call**

I'm testing the API using PostMan:

```
GET - http://srp.local/api/v1/runs/1
```

Authentication is done using a bearer token and this is working fine, I'm however having problems with the **/runs/{id}** call, all I want is for the call to return the run associated with that ID (basically a filtered version of the **/runs** call), but I'm struggling to get the parameter of the ID accross.

Currently, the code above works, but when trying to perform the aforementioned call, all it does is return the output for **/user** and doesn't return the run with the given ID.

I'm also not sure if I'm doing my routing optimally using the method above so any help would be appreciated - thank you.

Comment: Can you show your call data? i.e. from browser console or from wherever you are making the request. Your routes look fine.

Comment: @Rehmat I've updated the question with the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models can be resolved by using route-model binding, checkout the following example:

```
 Route::get('/runs/{run}', function(Request $request, Run $run) {
        $user = $request->user('api');


        return $user->run($run);
    });
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding

Using controllers is preferred over using callbacks in routes. Controllers help separating code  and allows caching. Checkout the following example: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#defining-controllers